# Codeigniter Database Query Question

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m doing the following queries in codeigniter and can’t figure out how to get the second query to work.  How do I get an array of just the values from my first query and use that in my second?

```
function application()
{
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $this->db->select('app_id')->from('using')->where('user_id' , $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $row = $query->result_array();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
    $this->db->select('app_name')->from('applications')->where('id' , $row['app_id']);
    $body['query'] = $this->db->get();
    endif;

    $this->load->view('apps_view', $body);
```

If I comment out the second query and `var_dump($row);`
it gives me:
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [“app_id”]=> string(1) “2” } [1]=> array(1) { [“app_id”]=> string(1) “3” } }

I decided to do multiple queries instead of a join because I will be adding additional columns to select from the second query.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does the second query return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you expecting the **first** query to return just **one** row?

If so then you should use:

```
$query = $this->db->get();

$row = $query->row();

$app_id = $row->app_id;
//etc
```

It's not clear from your question.

If your **first** query returns (or can return) multiple rows, then you need to do this:

```
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $this->db->select('app_name')
                 ->from('applications')
                 ->where('id' , $row['app_id']);
    }

    $body['query'] = $this->db->get();
endif;
// etc
```

you very may well need to adjust the code as I'm not sure what your desired result is. Do you see the difference?

If you return `result_array` you have an array of results (fancy that!) - hence why your `var_dump` has `[0]=> array(1)` etc - there is an array for each row returned.

If you are only wanting/expecting to return one result from the first query, you should use `row` instead.

Hope this makes sense - should be a push in the right direction.

**edit**
In fact this might be the correct syntax:

```
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) :
    $this->db->select('app_name')->from('applications');
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $this->db->where('id' , $row['app_id']);
        // build the `where...` string with iteration/result/row
    }

    $body['query'] = $this->db->get(); // now we get the data.
endif;
// etc
```

Comment: Ross, thanks for your help. Your assumption of my first query returning multiple rows is correct.  Sorry I didnt' explicitly state this.  The database query ends up being
    SELECT `event_name`
    FROM (`events`)
    WHERE `id` = '2'
    AND `id` = '3' `
whereas I want it to be WHERE id = 2 OR 3.

Comment: Sorry, now I'm probably really confusing you.  I'm trying to make this work with both applications and events, thus the different database query here, but it's still supposed to be the exact same.  It should read that the query ends up as SELECT app_name FROM (applications) WHERE id = '2' AND '3' --  instead I want it to be SELECT app_name FROM (applications) WHERE id = '2' OR id = '3'.  How could I change the statement to have it correct this query?  Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: you can use `$this->db->or_where();` for `OR` instead of `AND` more @ [the docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select)